# How to obtain namespace of a custom lang in Racket?

Tags: module, namespaces, racket, eval

I'm implementing a custom language in Racket in which I would like to provide an `eval` procedure bound to the namespace of this custom language.

*my-lang.rkt*:

```lisp
#lang racket

(provide #%module-begin #%top #%datum #%app)
(provide quote)
(provide (rename-out [a b] [my-eval eval]))

(define-namespace-anchor anchor)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace anchor)) ; wrong namespace

(define (my-eval x) (eval x ns))

(define a 1)
```

*test.rkt*:

```lisp
#lang s-exp "my-lang.rkt"

(eval 'a)
(eval 'b)
```

As implemented, since `ns` is the namespace of *my-lang.rkt*, `(eval 'a)` evaluates to `1` while `(eval 'b)` fails.

I would like `ns` to be bound to the namespace of *test.rkt* so that `(eval 'a)` fails and `(eval 'b)` returns `1`.

How should I define `ns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using parameter and macro. There might be a better way:

```
;; my-lang.rkt
#lang racket

(provide #%top #%datum #%app (rename-out [@#%module-begin #%module-begin])
         quote
         (rename-out [a b] [my-eval eval]))

(require syntax/parse/define
         racket/splicing)

(define current-ns (make-parameter #f))

(define-syntax-parser @#%module-begin
  [(_ . xs)
   #'(#%module-begin
      (define-namespace-anchor anchor)
      (splicing-parameterize ([current-ns (namespace-anchor->namespace anchor)])
        . xs))])

(define (my-eval x) (eval x (current-ns)))

(define a 1)
```

```
;; test.rkt
#lang s-exp "my-lang.rkt"

(eval 'b) ;=> 1
(eval 'a)
;; a: undefined;
;; cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```